# Class interface query

Tags: c++

I've been wondering about a design that I've been using for quite some time for my game engine and games. Let's say we have an Object class

```
class Object
{
    public: 
        const std::string& getName() { return m_name; }

    private:
        std::string m_name;
}
```

Then, I have a class called ObjectManager, which holds an instance of Object. Now, I've been wondering if I should keep that instance private in ObjectManager and duplicate code so that it could call getName(), or make Object public which defeats the concept of encapsulation. Which design do you guys think is better?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: btw, getName return type is void and you are returning a string

Comment: Yes, mistake on my part. I was typing the question on my phone and obviously wasn't paying close attention.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily consider the delegation to be duplication.  If you were to change the name of `Object::getName()` would it immediately imply that you also needed to change the name of `ObjectManager::getName()`?

Comment: What I mean by "duplication" is that I would need another method within ObjectManager to call Object::getName() since Object would be a private member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class contains an object that is usable by others, expose it.  Encapsulation is meant to hide variables needed to do something.  Certain data members don't fall into this.

Example:

Person tom;

```
    tom.getEyes().getColor();
    tom.getMouth().eat(tomato);
    tom.legs().walk();
```

Person could hide everything but it would be cumbersome:

```
    tom.getEyesColor(); // accessor for every eye feature
    tom.eat(tomato);   
    tom.walkAndEat();   // every possible combination of actions
```

Further example:

```
    grid.row(3).col(5).setText("hello");
```

Here a column class could expose many methods without the grid class having to be touched.  This is the beauty of object oriented programming.

If you named your class ObjectManager i get the feeling it is managing Object instances for others so you ought to expose it.  The other idea to use inheritance is also valid:

```
    class ObjectManager : public Object
    {
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the interface to methods only then keep the object private and use an accessor method that returns a const reference (and non const if needed) to the private object.

Also, inheritance is a good option if applicable.

Comment: This is actually the design I had originally, but I thought it was a bad coding style. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you consider the Object class to be well designed then it should not be bad to return a reference to an instance of Object

Comment: C++ containers expose the stored objects through reference

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing. If I understand your question correctly, I'd personally lean more towards making the Object a private member of ObjectManager and adding a function to ObjectManager to act as a proxy for Object::getName().  (Is this your question?)  However if you're just wrapping particularly thinly and are not trying to do something particularly technical or what have you, I might be tempted to answer otherwise. It depends, but more than likely, go ahead and make it private and add the extra function.  Note that this answer is based on the assumption that you're going to make heavy use out of inheritance here.

Comment: So far in the actual class that represents Object in my engine's codebase, it has over 60 methods which I have duplicated over in ObjectManager just so it can call the private member.

Comment: Is that every method Object has?  That really reduces the purpose behind it being private.  How many fields or operator overloads in Object are you NOT proxying in ObjectManager?  If there's a bunch of them, then neither approach is particularly better, I'd say.  But if there's next to nothing in Object without a proxy in ObjectManager, I'd say either 1) make the Object public instead, 2) find a way to simplify the proxying, or 3) inherit from Object instead.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the situation (Sorry for the non-answer!). If you do want to support strong encapsulation, you would probably want ObjectManager to look something like this:

```
public class ObjectManager
{
    private:
        Object obj;
    public:
        string GetNameOfInnerObject();
}
```

As you can see I changed the method header to be descriptive with respect to ObjectManager. This type of method naming can come in handy to abstract an object's more complex interactions within itself away.

Edit: It might help if you tell us what ObjectManager is supposed to do. Does it have any methods that don't correspond directly to your inner object?